# Sort orders by criterias

Tags: product, orders, date, history

I'm trying to display a history of customer's orders by products. I succeeded to display every product ordered with its date, name, price, sku and quantity. But now I'd like to display it by at least one criteria: the date.

The purpose is to offer the customer a list of his purchases per month.
How could I do it? Right now, I have done this in history.phtml file:

```
<?php 
    if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

        $orders= Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId());

            ?>

        <table class="data-table" id="my-orders-table">
            <thead>
            <tr class="first last">
                <th>Produit</th>
                <th>Référence</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th><span class="nobr">Prix</span></th>
                <th><span class="nobr">Quantités</span></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <?php
            foreach($orders as $eachOrder) {
                $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eachOrder->getId()); 

                $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
                $i = 0;

                foreach($items as $item): ?>
                    <tr class="first last odd">

                    <?php 
                        echo "<td>" . $item->getData()['name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $item->getData()['sku'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $this->formatDate($item->getData()['created_at']) . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $item->getData()['price'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . intval($item->getData()['qty_ordered']) . "</td>";
                    ?>
                    </tr>  
                <?php endforeach;
            }
    }

             ?>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**EDIT**
I edited my code and now I can sort my orders by month by adding a new attribute: addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('like' => date('Y') . '-10-%');

But I still don't know how to create a dropdown list to select the month and then refresh to sort products with the chosen month.
Thank you!

Comment: Just to say that I edited my code and now I can sort my orders by month by adding a new attribute: addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('like' => date('Y') . '-10-%');

But I still don't know how to create a dropdown list to select the month and then refresh to sort products with the chosen month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I wanted.
Here's my solution:

```
<div class="page-title"><h1>Mon historique par produit</h1></div>
<?php

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('date') && $this->getRequest()->getParam('date') != '11') {
            $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('like' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('date')."-%"));
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('date') && $this->getRequest()->getParam('date') == '11') {
            $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId());
        } else {
            $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('like' => date('Y-m')."-%"));
        }

?>

<form method="GET" action='.'>
    <p style="text-align: right;">Classer au 
    <select name="date">
        <?php 
            for ($i=11; $i > 0; $i--) { 
                echo "<option value='" . date('Y-m', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -" . (11 - $i) . " month")) . "'>" . date('Y-m', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -" . (11 - $i) . " month")) . "</option>";
            }
        ?>
        <option value="11">Depuis le début</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>

<table class="data-table" id="my-orders-table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="first last">
            <th>Produit</th>
            <th>Référence</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th><span class="nobr">Prix</span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr">Quantités</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
        $i = 1;
        $count = count($orders);
        echo "<h3>" . $count . " articles(s)</h3>";
        foreach($orders as $eachOrder) {
            $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eachOrder->getId()); 

            $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

            foreach($items as $item): ?>
                <?php if (($i++ % 2) == 0) {?>
                    <tr class="even">
                <?php } else {?>
                    <tr>

                    <?php 
                        }
                        $total += number_format($item->getData()['price'], 2);
                            echo "<td>" . $item->getData()['name'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $item->getData()['sku'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $this->formatDate($item->getData()['created_at']) . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . number_format($item->getData()['price'], 2, ',', '') . " €</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . intval($item->getData()['qty_ordered']) . "</td>";
                    ?>

                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;
            }

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('date') && $this->getRequest()->getParam('date') == '11') {
                echo "<tr><td><strong>Total : </strong>" .$total. "€</td></tr>";
            } else {
                echo "<tr><td><strong>Total sur le mois : </strong>" .$total. "€</td></tr>";
            }

    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```